# Android Communication with socket programming via WiFi Hotspot

Tags: android, wifimanager, hotspot

I have an application in android and I want to communicate through socket between my users which they connected each other via WiFi Hotspot.

Can I do such thing? If I can how can I get the connected users detail in my application?

2 user have installed my app, one of them creates a wifi hotspot and the other joins the hotspot. The first presses a button and sends a message like 'hello world' to the other via socket. Then on the second phone my app comes top and shows the message.

Comment: what kind of data do you want to exchange?

Comment: @lelloman just text

Comment: hum well of course you can do it, you can use java sockets, did you take a look at the java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html)?

Comment: @lelloman i allready wrote a communication program via socket in java. i did update my question

Comment: so what is the question than? it is a bit unclear what is the question about

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ getting user connection details in host of hotspot programmatically. then notify receiver. (how to)

Comment: Send them as text. You could do it you said.

Comment: `The first presses a button and sends a message like 'hello world' to the other via socket.`. Before sending a message,  using a socket, is possible a client app should first connect with a server app. Both apps should already be running.

Comment: `Then on the second phone my app comes top and shows the message.`. That app should already have been running and connected to the other app. Otherwise it could never receive a message.  But if it did it could come to the top indeed.

Comment: `one of them creates a wifi hotspot and the other joins the hotspot`. The devices are connected then. After that your client app should connect with the server app.

Comment: @greenapps ty. so i have got my first answer. i want to know ip and port of my client app in the server app programmatically. do you have any suggestion how can i reach this?

Comment: At which moment? Did the client app already establish a connection with the server app?

Comment: @greenapps in server app i created a wifi hotspot access and client app is connected to this access point. i can see the details in hotspot connected devices but i want to get this details programmatically

Comment: `and client app is connected to this access point.` Is it? I dont believe that. The client app has to connect with the server app. You client device is connected `connected devices` with the server device ak hotspot. Not your client app. With that you have the ip of the client device. That has nothing to do with your client app.

Comment: @greenapps yes you are right. in order to connect the client app to server app i guess i need the connection details of hotspot.

Comment: `i want to know ip and port of my client app in the server app`. For what? If your client wants to connect with the server app the client should know ip if the server. And the port. Dont be so vague talking about details.

Comment: @greenapps oh yes! i just figured it out. thank you